# map lambda in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, polygon, plotly-python

I'm trying to use a plotly example in Python 3, but getting a syntax error in this line:

```
return map(lambda (x, y, an): (x, y), cornersWithAngles)
```

I already read that using parentheses to unpack the arguments in a lambda is not allowed in Python 3, but I don't know how exactly to adjust my code to solve that problem.

Here is the complete code (error is on line 16):

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF

import scipy

def PolygonSort(corners):
    n = len(corners)
    cx = float(sum(x for x, y in corners)) / n
    cy = float(sum(y for x, y in corners)) / n
    cornersWithAngles = []
    for x, y in corners:
        an = (np.arctan2(y - cy, x - cx) + 2.0 * np.pi) % (2.0 * np.pi)
        cornersWithAngles.append((x, y, an))
    cornersWithAngles.sort(key = lambda tup: tup[2])
    return map(lambda (x, y, an): (x, y), cornersWithAngles)

def PolygonArea(corners):
    n = len(corners)
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area

corners = [(0, 0), (3, 0), (2, 10), (3, 4), (1, 5.5)]
corners_sorted = PolygonSort(corners)
area = PolygonArea(corners_sorted)

x = [corner[0] for corner in corners_sorted]
y = [corner[1] for corner in corners_sorted]

annotation = go.Annotation(
    x=5.5,
    y=8.0,
    text='The area of the polygon is approximately %s' % (area),
    showarrow=False
)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    mode='markers',
    fill='tozeroy',
)

layout = go.Layout(
    annotations=[annotation],
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[-1, 9]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        range=[-1, 12]
    )
)

trace_data = [trace1]
fig = go.Figure(data=trace_data, layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig, filename='polygon-area')
```

Comment: I'm getting: `tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in python3`..

Answer (score 1):

Just use `x` as a tuple, maybe this may help:

```
map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), cornerWithEdges)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do (parameter unpacking in `lambda`) worked in Python 2, but does not work anymore in Python 3.

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
>>> lst = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
>>> map(lambda (a,b,c): (a,b), lst)
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8)]

Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
>>> lst = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]
>>> map(lambda (a,b,c): (a,b), lst)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    map(lambda (a,b,c): (a,b), lst)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There are a few things you can do instead, though.

```
>>> list(map(lambda t: t[:2], lst))
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8)]
>>> [(a,b) for a, b, c in lst]
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8)]
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(lambda a, b, c: (a, b), lst))
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (7, 8)]
```

Personally, I'd go with the list-comprehension or generator-expression.
Also, remember that in Python 3 `map` is a generator, and not a list, so when using `map` you might have to wrap the result in a `list`, depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation :-) 
I replaced:
`return map(lambda (x, y, an): (x, y), cornersWithAngles)`

with:
`return list(starmap(lambda x, y, an: (x, y), cornersWithAngles))` 

I hope that's the right use of your code for my example – the code seems to work and gives me the same area as in the python 2.7 example.

Comment: @sarahp That's fine, but instead, why not try the list comprehension? That's shorter, does not need any imports, more readable and probably even faster. But of course that's entirely up to you.

Comment: I didn't know which variable I should use for "t" in my code – that's why I chose the more complicated solution ;-)